# cjson decoding error on identical code

Tags: php, json

Trying to post JSON data using PHP, but this text is displayed - {"message":"cjson decoding error","code":500,"error":true}

This is the data which is submitted via browser (used Live HTTP Headers plugin to get it):

> {"nodes":[{"id":"fbm:n#1445506477266","type":"bookmark","parentId":"ROOT","refId":null,"href":"","text":"[New Bookmark]","desc":"","tags":"","cr":1445506584}],"revision":1,"token":"MTQ0NTUwNjQ3Ny4yOS1O9m2hacygwtDuox8/fHtN/efVUtNC9RvMlQbPAS+gwg=="}

This is my data:

```
json_encode(array("nodes"=>array(array("id"=>"fbm:n#1445506477266", "type"=>"bookmark", "parentId"=>"ROOT","refId"=>null,"href"=>"","text"=>"[New Bookmark]","desc"=>"","tags"=>"","cr"=>1445506584)), "revision"=>1,"token"=>"MTQ0NTUwNjQ3Ny4yOS1O9m2hacygwtDuox8/fHtN/efVUtNC9RvMlQbPAS+gwg=="))
```

When I print my data, I get exactly the same (except that json_encode function escapes / with \, but I read it doesn't matter in JSON). So here's the output of my data

> {"nodes":[{"id":"fbm:n#1445506477266","type":"bookmark","parentId":"ROOT","refId":null,"href":"","text":"[New Bookmark]","desc":"","tags":"","cr":1445506584}],"revision":1,"token":"MTQ0NTUwNjQ3Ny4yOS1O9m2hacygwtDuox8/fHtN/efVUtNC9RvMlQbPAS+gwg=="}

As you see, everything is identical (except ). Even used Beyond Compare utility to compare every character of of the code between these, no differences.

How it comes the code still returns decode error? Tried using JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES as well (so no slashes are added), no result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your token is not true.

you can check with this code ;

```
$a = json_encode(array("nodes"=>array(array("id"=>"fbm:n#1445506477266", "type"=>"bookmark", "parentId"=>"ROOT","refId"=>null,"href"=>"","text"=>"[New Bookmark]","desc"=>"","tags"=>"","cr"=>1445506584)), "revision"=>1,"token"=>"MTQ0NTUwNjQ3Ny4yOS1O9m2hacygwtDuox8/fHtN/efVUtNC9RvMlQbPAS+gwg=="));

print_r($a);

echo '<br>';

echo '{"nodes":[{"id":"fbm:n#1445506477266","type":"bookmark","parentId":"ROOT","refId":null,"href":"","text":"[New Bookmark]","desc":"","tags":"","cr":1445506584}],"revision":1,"token":"MTQ0NTUwNjQ3Ny4yOS1O9m2hacygwtDuox8/fHtN/efVUtNC9RvMlQbPAS+gwg=="}';
```

Edit: JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES is working for me.

```
$a = array("nodes"=>array(array("id"=>"fbm:n#1445506477266", "type"=>"bookmark", "parentId"=>"ROOT","refId"=>null,"href"=>"","text"=>"[New Bookmark]","desc"=>"","tags"=>"","cr"=>1445506584)), "revision"=>1,"token"=>"MTQ0NTUwNjQ3Ny4yOS1O9m2hacygwtDuox8/fHtN/efVUtNC9RvMlQbPAS+gwg==");
json_encode($a,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

print_r($a);
echo '<br><br><br>';
echo '{"nodes":[{"id":"fbm:n#1445506477266","type":"bookmark","parentId":"ROOT","refId":null,"href":"","text":"[New Bookmark]","desc":"","tags":"","cr":1445506584}],"revision":1,"token":"MTQ0NTUwNjQ3Ny4yOS1O9m2hacygwtDuox8/fHtN/efVUtNC9RvMlQbPAS+gwg=="}';
```

Comment: What do you mean the token is not true? I launched your code and the only difference is backslashes (which aren't important in JSON from my experience). As explained in my question, I also tested without backslashes without any success.

Comment: I'm sorry, I saw it now. With Json_unescaped_slashes , it seems ok. Are you still getting decoding error ?

Comment: Can you try this in your code instead of JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES ?   str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($json_data));

Comment: The same. It has nothing to do with backslashes, because there are also tokens that do NOT have any slashes, and the same decoding error is always displayed.